# Android - play and stop different mediaplayer, clicking on different buttons

Tags: java, android, button, android-mediaplayer

I have multi buttons and multi song when I clicked in another button the first button dont stop 
Assume I have two buttons: Button1 and Button2. If I click on Button1 then audio file A.mp3 plays. After this click on Button2 then audio file A.mp3 stops and B.mp3 plays. Then again click on Button1 to stop B.mp3 and play A.mp3 instantly and so on.

This is what i have tried so far

```
final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
JSONArray songs = (JSONArray) response.getJSONArray("songs");
for ( int i = 0; i < songs.length(); i++) 
{
    // Create LinearLayout
   audio = songs.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_AUDIO) ;
   String chanson = songs.getJSONObject(i).getString("title") ;
   String duration = songs.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_DURATION) ;

   LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
   ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

   final TextView txtchanson = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   txtchanson.setText(chanson);
   txtchanson.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
   TextView txtduration = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   txtduration.setText(duration);

   final Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
   final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
   mp.setAudioSessionId(i+1);

   mp.setDataSource(audio); 
   mp.prepare();

   btn.setId(i+1);
   btn.setTypeface(ionicons);
   btn.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
   btn.setLayoutParams(params);

   final int index = i;

   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Clicked Button Index :" +  btn.getId(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (btn.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {

                btn.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));
                txtchanson.setTextColor(R.color.green);
                mp.start();
            } else if (btn.getText() == getString(R.string.pause_str)) {
                mp.pause();
                btn.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
                txtchanson.setTextColor(R.color.gray);
            }
        }
     });

     ll.addView(btn);
     ll.addView(txtchanson);
     ll.addView(txtduration);

     lm.addView(ll);
}
```

Comment: Are you creating layouts for every song?

Comment: What does currently happen? Why doesn't it work? `btn.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)` should be `btn.getText().equals(getString(R.string.play_str))`

Comment: it does not work ,when I click on the two buttons play ! !!!

Answer (score 0):

Once a user taps on file1 then the file1 start play. And when user taps on another file, the file1 pause the playing and start playing for the tapped file. This should happen for all file.